# AXIS2 client calling cxf web service operations

Tags: web, service, cxf, apache-axis

I have wsdl file and corresponding web service operations are implemented using CFX.
From the wsdl, I have to generate the stub using AXIS2 API. 
Can someone let me know if it feasible to make call to CFX web service from AXIS2 client stub.